# typeScript не видит метод fill у экземпляра объекта Array

Tags: typescript

Пытаюсь понять TypeScript, но не могу разобраться в какой-то простейшей ошибке и не у кого спросить, почему в js метод fill у объекта Array есть и в обучающем ролике у мужика он тоже есть, но у моего TypeScript его почему-то нет ну или он его просто не видит почему? версии node-js и typeScript указал в терминале.

```
 let arr:Array<Number>=new Array(8);
 arr.fill(0);
```

[image: typeScript жалуется на метод fill у объекта]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В сообщении об ошибке как правило дается рекомендация по её исправлению:

```
TS2550: Property 'fill' does not exist on type 'Number[]'.
Do you need to change your target library? 
Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2015' or later.
```

В данном случае рекомендуется добавить в конфигурационный файл (обычно это `tsconfig.json`) для опции `lib` значение `es2015`. Если этого файла у вас ещё нет, то можно создать его через меню `File` -> `New` -> `tsconfig.json File`. В новый файл, в раздел `compilerOptions` нужно добавить строку `"lib": ["es2015"]` (`es2015` - это минимальное значение, можно и более новое, например `es2019`)

Результат будет выглядеть приблизительно так:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["es2015"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Параметров у файла `tsconfig.json` очень много, информации о нем в интернете тоже предостаточно, например [официальное руководство](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) или [эта статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/542234/) .

Comment: Cпасибо тебе добрый человек!